# case_when() to replace characters in a column with numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I have a dataframe in R like this:

```
myDf <- data.frame(Name = c("Al","Jon","Jack","Reed"),
                   State = c("", "", "Ohio","Texas"))
```

I want to replace empty values in `myDf$State` with a 0, and character values in `myDf$State` with a 1. So far I tried:

```
myDf %>%
  mutate(State = case_when(is.character(State) ~ 1))
```

which doesn't work, as `is.character(myDf$State)` is `TRUE` (i.e., the whole column `myDf$State` is of class character). Original data has several different words in `myDf$State`, so it would be too demanding to replace them by constructing a string like `c("Ohio","Texas")`. Desired output:

```
  Name State
1   Al     0
2  Jon     0
3 Jack     1
4 Reed     1
```

Comment: `ifelse(State == "", 0, 1)`

Comment: @zeprhryl it was so easy and yet I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: In a data.frame all the values of a same variable necessarily have the same class, so you cannot distinguish values of a variable based on their class

Answer (score 3):

Use `nzchar`:

> nzchar is a fast way to find out if elements of a character vector are
> non-empty strings.

```r
myDf %>%
  mutate(State = +nzchar(State))

  Name State
1   Al     0
2  Jon     0
3 Jack     1
4 Reed     1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to test if `myDf$State` is not `""` and convert it to 0 and 1 using `+`.

```
+(myDf$State != "")
#[1] 0 0 1 1
```

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(
"ifelse" = ifelse(myDf$State == "", 0, 1),
"+ !=" = +(myDf$State != ""),
"nzchar" = +nzchar(myDf$State) )
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 ifelse      12.05µs 23.81µs  46551.      0B    9.31  9998     2 214.8ms <dbl> 
#2 + !=         1.74µs  1.91µs 513162.      0B    0    10000     0  19.5ms <int> 
#3 nzchar       1.41µs  1.56µs 618714.      0B    0    10000     0  16.2ms <int>
```

Using `nzchar` is in this case the fastest.